# Load same url after validation failed

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Validation is working fine. On Add action loading the new form for the user to fill in. Once submitted the validation is done on processAdd(). All is fine.

**Problem:**

User fill in the form at `http://localhost:8000/Struts2_Spring_Crud/student/add`.When submitted than processed & validated through `http://localhost:8000/Struts2_Spring_Crud/student/processAdd`. If validation failed my url is /processAdd. I want to be at /add when validation fails. Is there any way to do this?

```
<s:form action="processAdd" method="POST">
    <s:submit method="execute" value="#title"/>
 </s:form>

  public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("execute() executed");
        //Process form data
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String input() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("input() executed");
        //Prepare form data
        return INPUT;
    }

     <default-action-ref name="list"/>
        <action name="list" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction" method="getAllStudents">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/student.list.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="add" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction" method="input">
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/student.edit.tiles</result>
            <result name="failure" type="tiles">/student.edit.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="processAdd" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">list</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/student.edit.tiles</result>
            <result name="failure" type="redirectAction">add</result>
        </action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<action name="processAdd" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction">
  <result name="success" type="redirectAction">list</result>
  <result name="input" type="redirectAction">add</result>
  <result name="failure" type="redirectAction">add</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks. Working fine. One question. How can I repopulate my textfield when I am redirecting between actions?. Any help on this.

Comment: i'm not sure, what u meant `repoplate textfield`, but actually you do not need to actions for this, check out my answer of another your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765997/struts2-disable-validation-on-page-load

Comment: Replied there please check. I accept this answer. Please help me with that question link above in your comment.